# Androidアプリで毎日APIの情報を取得したい

Tags: java, android

Androidアプリで毎日0時にAPIの情報を取得する機能を実装したいです。
深夜なのでアプリを起動しなくてもAPIの情報を取得してほしいのですが、TimerやWorkManagerを使ってもできません。
実装中につき短時間で定期実行するようにしていますが、アプリ起動時、バックグラウンド時は定期的に実行できています。
以下が該当部分です。

```
private void startWork(int num){
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String current = getStringDate(currentTime);
    //Workerに渡すデータ作成
    Data data = new Data.Builder().putInt("num",num).build();
    //WorkRequestの作成（PeriodicWorkRequestを使って20分ごとに定期実行
    PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            SampleWorker.class,1,TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInputData(data)
            .addTag(SampleWorker.WORK_TAG).build();
    //キューに登録（スケジューリング）
    WorkManager manager = WorkManager.getInstance(this);
    manager.enqueue(request);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Worker scheduled"+current);

}
```

Comment: 「アプリを起動しなくてもAPIの情報を取得してほしい」って、じゃぁ何が情報の取得をするというのですか？
何がしたいのかを具体的に、誰にでもわかるように書かないと回答が得られないように思います。

Comment: 「アプリを起動しなくても」というのは不可能で、指定時間になったらアプリをバックグラウンドで起動し、処理することになると思います。ただ、「APIの情報を取得する目的」が分からないので、Fumu 7さんもおっしゃっているように、皆さん適切な回答が難しいんじゃないでしょうか。例えば、タイマーアプリ的な効果を狙っているのか、実はサーバー内部で毎日0時のデータを取得・保管しておいて次の呼び出し時（利用者が画面をONにした時等）にAndroid端末側とデータを同期したほうがいいのか等、色んなケースがあり、ベストな手段が変わってきます。タイマー的なものは特殊でバッテリー消費が激しいため、実務的には他の手段が取れるならまず選びませんし、他のケースでもアプリが最終的に何をしたいのかによって色々変わってきます。